# I am trying to use ffmpeg to separate audio from video, but after downloading the ffmpeg build I cannot seem to activate it in Power Shell

Tags: powershell, audio, video, ffmpeg, winzip

Ok, look y'all, I am NOT an aspiring programmer. I'm simply trying to separate audio from video of a youtube video I downloaded.

What I've done:

Downloaded YT vid using 4k video Downloader

I downloaded ffmpeg build from https://ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows

I downloaded WinZip in order to access the ffmpeg files.

I thought I used winzip correctly, but whenever I paste the command code line recommended to me, ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:a pcm_s16le audio.wav, I receive the following:

> PS C:\Users\user\Videos\4K Video Downloader> ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:a
> pcm_s16le audio.wav ffmpeg : The term 'ffmpeg' is not recognized as
> the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
> the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
>
> - ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -c:a pcm_s16le audio.wav
> - ```
>     + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ffmpeg:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
>   ```
>
> PS C:\Users\user\Videos\4K Video Downloader>

This is all Phoenician to me, but what I take away is that I have not completed some step to fully incorporate the ffmpeg code into my system. I believe that I am not using Winzip correctly.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: See https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20495/how-do-i-set-up-and-use-ffmpeg-in-windows

Comment: `ExecutableName Arguments ...` only works if executable can be found through `PATH` environment variable.